# Laravel 5 one to N relation issue

Tags: laravel-5

I have a `recipes` table , `ingredients` table and `units` table.
an ingredient has one unit
a unit belongs to many ingredients

Now that being said, I should be able to get the unit for a given ingredient like so:

```
@foreach ($recipe->ingredients as $ingredient)
    <li>
       {{ $ingredient->pivot->quantity}}

       {{ $ingredient->unit->name}}   <------- like this

       {{ $ingredient->name}}
    </li>
@endforeach
```

but it doesn't

here are the relations in my models:

**Ingredient.php**:

```
public function unit()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Unit');
}
```

**Unit.php**:

```
public function ingredients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredient');
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, what I did is the following relation in my **Ingredient** model:

```
public function unit()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Unit','id','unit_id');
}
```

the second parameter is the primary key of the units table and the third parameter *unit_id* is the reference to unit in the `ingredients` table

in my view i can do:

> {{ $ingredient->unit->name}}